# Ant continues to add the wrong jar file to the classpath even after I've changed it

Tags: java, ant, jdeveloper, toplink

I have a desktop java app, that runs perfectly in the IDE, but won't run as a stand-alone application. The problem I am having is that I'm upgrading to MYSQL 8 from 5.1. To complicate matters for myself I'm also using JDeveloper now instead of NetBeans. So I'm under a huge learning curve. However the problem is that when I run my ant script against my java files, it uses the old mysql-connector jar file instead of the newer one I've put into the library list. It builds the manifest.mf file with the outdated connector and nothing I've done seems to fix that. I need some guidance.

[image]

So the library at the top is the MYSQL connector I want to use.
this picture has the definition of the jar file.
[image]

Here is the Manifest.mf file created by the ANT script, I've highlighted the mysql-connector jar file that it uses, instead of the one I've previously set up in the library.

[image]

Here it the copylibs section of the ANT build script.

```
    <target name="-init-macrodef-copylibs">
        <macrodef name="copylibs" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3">
            <attribute default="${manifest.file}" name="manifest"/>
            <element name="customize" optional="true"/>
            <sequential>
                <property location="${build.classes.dir}" name="build.classes.dir.resolved"/>
                <pathconvert property="run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir">
                    <path path="${run.classpath}"/>
                    <map from="${build.classes.dir.resolved}" to=""/>
                </pathconvert>
                <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="jar.classpath">
                    <path path="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}"/>
                    <chainedmapper>
                        <flattenmapper/>
                        <filtermapper>
                            <replacestring from=" " to="%20"/>
                        </filtermapper>
                        <globmapper from="*" to="lib/*"/>
                    </chainedmapper>
                </pathconvert>
                <taskdef classname="org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.copylibstask.CopyLibs" classpath="${libs.CopyLibs.classpath}" name="copylibs"/>
                <copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" manifestencoding="UTF-8" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" excludes="${dist.archive.excludes}"/>
                    <manifest>
                        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
                        <customize/>
                    </manifest>
                </copylibs>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
    </target>
```

Comment: Do not use images for textual information.

Comment: Since you're in upgrading mode, I'd strongly urge you to upgrade away from Ant altogether. Ant is really dead, only remaining on life support in Netbeans, where it wheezes still in mangled and unmaintainable form.
Don't get me wrong - I used to like Ant as it was intuitive and (as long as Netbeans wasn't involved), easy to maintain and extend.
You want to be using Maven or Gradle these days. I gravitate to the former. Moving your project to a different IDE should have been painless had you been doing so.

Unfortunately, you've made it difficult to help directly, as you've posted images.

Comment: Jdeveloper has something called deploy which I've been trying to use. Honestly it's worse than ANT IMHO. It refuses to do a build unless you have something that needs to be compiled. So if you just change a library you also have to change something in a java file as well. It also doesn't seem to want to build a proper MANIFEST file, nor copy any of the libraries to the lib directory. That's what led me to ANT.

Comment: Can somebody tell me where Ant is getting the list of files to copy?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're referring to specifically but Ant uses `fileset` elements for that, generally

Comment: Your description was cut off at the first line. I did find the project.properties file that had the filesets in it. I ended up updating the fileset name to point to the new file. It now looks like: file.reference.mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar=../../lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar    It's not a good compromise but it works. I'm wondering how this properties file is created.